# Connect to Ldap and Authenticate user with asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have to authenticate my user credentials in my asp.NET web api with ldap server and if success token is given have to check whether the user has access to controller with another table with contains user role and id

I have tried with token based authentication but could not implement the table authorization part